# Change displayed number of products WooCommerce shop issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Hello I changed my function.php to

```
/**
 * Change number of products that are displayed per page (shop page)
 */
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
  // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options –> Reading
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $cols = 9;
  return $cols;
}
```

and now my shop doesn't display the items shop in shop page
And now I'd like to return to default , i deleted the lines in my function.php but still doesn't work. Which filter i have to add to return back?

Comment: Just remove the code from your active theme's functions.php file and save. Empty your site cache if enabled. Otherwise restore on your site a database a backup.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I did this, but still can't see nothing :(

Comment: @LoicTheAztec now I can see it again, but this code doesn't work It was cache stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
/**
  * WC: change products per page
  * @return int
  */
function so22835795_loop_shop_per_page() {
    return -1; //return any number, -1 === show all
};
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', 'so22835795_loop_shop_per_page', 10, 0);
```